# Error convirtiendo datos varchar a float SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de convertir y sumar un resultado pero me regresa los valores que contienen un formato de miles `'1,000.00'` como NULL

mi query es el siguiente

```
select [material], [materialDescripcion], [bUn] as [um], [crcy], 
SUM(try_cast(unrestricted AS float)) AS unrestricted
from [mb52] 
where [deleted_at] is null group by [material], [crcy], [materialDescripcion], [bUn], [unrestricted]
```

uno de los datos que tengo es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

le coloco el try_cast por que de lo contrario me arroja el erro que no puede convertir varchar a float

ya tambien trate usando CONVERT(float, unrestricted) y me arroja error `Error converting data type varchar to float.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Tienes que quitar el separador de miles antes para poder convertir
- Evita usar el `float` a menos que se trate de algo que necesites una precisión científica, para aplicaciones comerciales es preferible usar los datos tipo `NUMERIC` o `DECIMAL` de precisión fija.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(15,2), REPLACE('1,000.00', ',', ''))
```

En tu caso:

```
select [material], 
       [materialDescripcion], 
       [bUn] as [um], 
       [crcy], 
       SUM(try_cast(REPLACE(unrestricted, ',', '') AS NUMERIC(15,2))) AS unrestricted
       from [mb52] 
       where [deleted_at] is null 
       group by [material], 
                [crcy], 
                [materialDescripcion], 
                [bUn]
```

Por cierto, si estás haciendo un `SUM` sobre `[unrestricted]` no lo agregues al `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Si ya descubriste que el error son las comas, lo único que hay que hacer es removerlas usando `REPLACE()`.

```
SELECT  [material], 
        [materialDescripcion], 
        [bUn] as [um], 
        [crcy], 
        SUM(TRY_CAST( REPLACE( unrestricted, ',', '') AS float)) AS unrestricted
FROM [mb52] 
WHERE [deleted_at] IS NULL 
GROUP BY [material], 
        [crcy], 
        [materialDescripcion], 
        [bUn];
```

También hay que quitar la columna que estás sumando del `GROUP BY`.